# :Extract and Replace a substring using Regex in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, replace, extract

I have a string which contains the following substring one or more than one times:

```
(DynamicContent(abc.xyz))
```

I want to replace this whole substring with a different string which depends on `abc` and `xyz`. Therefore, I want to first extract both of them seperately.
All this has to be done using Java.

Example:
Input String : `(DynamicContent(box-shadow.css)):0px 2px 10px #330000;`
Output String : `-moz-box-shadow:0px 2px 10px #330000;` (Depends on the client's browser)

I find out the output string using `box-shadow` and `css`.

Comment: Maybe you could show us an example input and output.

Comment: a little more clarity in the question is needed. Please elaborate further, possible with examples.

Comment: String: (DynamicContent(box-shadow.css))
Output: -moz-box-shadow (Depending on the client's browser)

I also want 'box-shadow' and 'css' in different string variables.

Comment: I have edited my question. Hope it pretty clear now.

Answer (score 0):

`\(DynamicContent\(box-shadow\.css\)\)` should match, just escape all the [metacharacters](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions).

In Java regex:

`\\(DynamicContent\\(box-shadow\\.css\\)\\)`

To get box-shadow and css in different groups use:

`\\(DynamicContent\\((box-shadow)\\.(css)\\)\\)` if you only need to match this particular string or a more all purpose: `\\(DynamicContent\\((.+)\\.(\\w+)\\)\\)`

Comment: I also want to retrieve box-shadow and css as different strings.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I'd create a regex pattern for the DynamicContent snippet with matcher groups for the text before the DynamicContent and your two parameters (abc and xyz). Then you can scan your text using the Matcher.find() method repeatingly and build you output using the values of your matcher groups.

Answer (score 0):

This will find your groups :

```
List<String> matchList = new ArrayList<String>();
try {
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\(([^(]+)\\.([^)]+)");
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
    while (regexMatcher.find()) {
        matchList.add(regexMatcher.group(1));
        matchList.add(regexMatcher.group(2));
    } 
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

When applied to :

```
(DynamicContent(abc.xyz))
```

It gets the contents of the inner parentheses and groups whatever is before . to group 1 and whatever is after . to group 2.

Hope it helps :)